# Trying to pass argument to exe file using php popen and reading it from fread but unable to read the correct output

Tags: php, arguments, exe, popen, fread

Its simple c# console app, for addition of two numbers, I am invoking this exe from php and passing 2 argument 5 and 6, expecting output would be sum of two numbers but I am getting output as "x:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Though file has executed successfully. Seems issue with fread.

```
 PHP:

  <?php  

  $handle = popen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/sum.exe 5 6 2>&1', 'r');
  $read ='';

  while (!feof($handle)) 
  {
     $read .= fread($handle, 8192);
  }
  echo $read;
  pclose($handle);
 ?>

C#:

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int result = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
  Console.Write(result.ToString());
}
```

However, if I return simple string from c# and then call it though this exe from php without any argument then its working fine . e.g.

```
 static void Main(string[] args) 
 { 
  Console.Write("check"); 
 }

   <?php 
     $handle = popen(dirname(FILE) . '/sum.exe', 'r'); 
     $read =''; 
      while (!feof($handle)) { 
        $read .= fread($handle, 8192); 
       } 
     echo $read; 
     pclose($handle); 
    ?>
```

Comment: there is a quoting error in the above ( `'/sum.exe 5 6' 2>&1'` ) ~ does this same error exist in your actual code?

Comment: its typo but actual code is correct i.e. $handle = popen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/sum.exe 5 6 2>&1', 'r');

Comment: Improve the title: What is the actual problem? The file not being found, the file not being executes, the parameters not being passed, the result being wrong, the result being read incorrectly? Also improve the English in the question if you can.

Comment: File is getting executed but the output is not correct. ideally it should be 11 instead "x:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." However, if I return simple string and then call it without any argument its working as expected. e.g.  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("check");
        }<?php
$handle = popen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/sum.exe', 'r');
echo "'$handle'; " . gettype($handle) . "\n";
$read ='';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $read .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
echo $read;
pclose($handle);
?>

Comment: Don't add a comment: **Edit** your question to improve it!